# Adding a link to a node in a Views export

Tags: views

I'm using Views data export to export a view-based search as a CSV file for users. Basically it's working. However I'd like to customize how some of the fields come out in the CSV.

Specifically for this question I'm interested in learning how to export the link to the NODE that is returned. It doesn't have to be an active link per se (although that would be ideal), but just the URL to the node would be great too.

I've tried adding Content: Link to the Fields area but that just exports as 'View' for every single returned node. Not helpful.

I've tried returning my title which is currently set to link to the original content but the export doesn't return it as a link. It just returns the title.

I've tried returning the title and making it return as a link with Content: Link as the URL (absolute path selected). But that doesn't nothing.

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a new field "content:path" and check the option in the rewrite results section "Use absolute link (begins with "http://")". This should do what you want.

If you want to output it as a working link, you can check the option " Output this field as a link" and fill the replacement pattern [path] into "Link path".